# htaccess rewrite being overwritten

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following htaccess file in the root of my site to redirect a directory 'MyDirectory' to another URL (to stop google indexing both sites)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^myurl\.co\.uk$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.myurl\.co\.uk$
RewriteRule ^mydirectory\/(.*)$$ "http\:\/\/www\.redirectURL\.com/" [R=301,NC]
```

I then have another htaccess file in the 'MyDirectory' directory above which handles the URL and query string in a user friendly way:

```
RewriteRule ^Answers/(.+)$ Answers.php?articleName=$1 [QSA]
```

However, when i have the *ReWriteRule ^Answers...* section in my other htaccess it stops the redirect in the root of my site from working.

Any suggestions why the ^Answers/... rewrite is overwritting my redirect to www.redirectURL.com.

Thanks

Comment: Which URL are you trying?

Comment: myurl.co.uk/MyDirectory

Answer (score 0):

`.htaccess` is per directory directive and for any URI path it current directory's `.htaccess` is processed first. If no .htaccess is found then it starts going 1 level up the directory tree until it finds one. It processes `DocumentRoot/.htaccess` in the end.

In your case since you have a `/MyDirectory/.htaccess` therefore all the directives are read from that file only thus overriding all the rules of `DocumentRoot/.htaccess`.

However you can add this line after `RewriteEngine On` in `/MyDirectory/.htaccess`

```
RewriteOptions inherit
```

This will process parent .htaccess after completing current one.